# Will individual irrigation branches with varying numbers of holes flow at the same rate?

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure

So I have ridiculously hard water at my place. Like, it's gravel coming out of the tap. Terrible. Drip irrigation doodads clog up in about 3 months... if that.

I have many new fruit trees that I want to irrigate this season, in groups up to six. So my solution is to use ring sections of pex pipe about 4 feet long (~1.25 ft dia) , with 4 1/16 or 1/8 in holes dilled into them. These rings are wrapped in landscape fabric and covered with pine bark mulch so that water will seep into the ground slowly.

I plan on no more than 6 trees per zone. Basically each zone looks like this:

[image]

Now ... my concern is not about the ***amount*** of flow, but that they all flow ***evenly***. My intuition tells me that, since water is essentially incompressible, as long as there is *some* pressure in the system, all the pressures will be equal at point A,B,C and D. And since the flow is intended to be very slow, I'm not counting friction flow in the pipe.

***MY QUESTION:*** Should these individual sprinklers all flow at around the same rate, even if one has more holes than the others?

The reason for going to this trouble is that I don't want to mess with soaker hoses or drippers, misters, etc. because they get clogged easily with the minerals. If the holes get clogged I can just clean them with a nail and put them back into service.

Comment: Before buying the trees, have your water tested and make sure the trees will enjoy what is in the water.  Too much of a good thing can be as bad as too little.  Not sure but you might want/need something like a double Y for the pipe instead of a straight main feed pipe.

Answer (score 1):

You will have pressure/flow drop at every outlet.

For that the last outlet will get least water flow.

How much will depend on the capacity of the supply line.

You can compensate by reducing the flow on the first ones and increase towards the end.

Comment: Adding to that, since you are making the holes.  Start off with fewer holes than you intend and install it.  Look at the water flow and add more holes as required.